# Why It is not going to work with method which is after main method?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am automating web application. I want to run methods parallel , So have written code like :

```
public class test{

public static WebDriver driver;

public static void main(String args[])
{    
     driver = new FirefoxDriver();       
}

public static void Login()
{   
  driver.get("www.example.com");
  driver.findElement(By.id("uname")).sendKeys("test");
  driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("test");    
}
}
```

When I run the program , it just opens browser and then nothing. Why is it not going inside Login method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you calling the `Login` method from the `main`?

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

 driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 Login();

}
```

What do you mean by `I want to run the methods in parallel`?

Comment: I see. Simple but I was not aware. Thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: @HelpingHands, if you are new to webdriver/java, I would advise you to take a look here - http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-testcase/

Answer (score 1):

You need the call the `Login()` method inside `main()` to execute it.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    Login();
}
```

> I want to run methods parallel.

You need to create threads and launch them for running any code in parallel in java.

`Main` is the starting point for any java program. Once it starts executing the `Main` method, you can launch multiple thread by implementing `Runnable` interface or extending `Thread` class. You would need to define the parallel thread code by overriding `run()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Someone will have to call the `Login()` method to do the work ... Currently, its just defined but not in use ...